# Entity Framework Stored Procedure Returning Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that performs some actions on given parameters and returns a set of data.  I do not need the returned data, so my code does not attempt to read the data.  However, after making the call, any subsequent actions on the context raise the error

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

I can work around this by converting the returned enumerator into a list, however, is there any way to ignore the data returned by the stored procedure and free the context for further use?

The stored procedure is used in several applications and updating/changing it is not an option.  I am using Entity Framework 5 with a database first approach.

To clarify, there is no loop and the only difference between the working code and non-working code is the `.ToList()` added to the stored procedure call.

The code is something like

```
var SomeEntityVal = Context.SomeEntity.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 1);
Context.SomeSPWithReturnType("Foo", SomeEntityVal.Id);
SomeEntity.SomeProperty = "OtherVal";
Context.SaveChanges(); // Exception raised
```

vs

```
var SomeEntityVal = Context.SomeEntity.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 1);
Context.SomeSPWithReturnType("Foo", SomeEntityVal.Id).ToList(); // Note .ToList()
SomeEntity.SomeProperty = "OtherVal";
Context.SaveChanges(); // Changed saved successfully
```

Comment: are you using loop in saving into database?

Comment: it would be better if you put some code

Comment: Why just don't call SP in a separate transaction?

Comment: Nevermind, I have managed to resolve the issue by changing the return type for the Function in EDMX. Thanks.